Example of a non-finitely generated fractional ideal
I am following Atiyah-Macdonald. I know a finitely generated ideal is fractional and invertible ideals are finitely generated.
I want to construct a non-invertible fractional ideal. So I need to construct a fractional ideal which is not finitely generated. So what is the example of a fractional ideal which is not finitely generated. In a Noetherian ring, I know it is not possible. Any suggestions?

Let $v:K\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ be a (non-archimedian) valuation with value group $\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the valuation ring $O\subset K$ of this valuation. It is not noetherian. The set
$
J:=\{x\in K : v(x)>-\sqrt{2}\}
$
is an $O$-submodule of $K$. It is not finitely generated: if it were, it would have a single generator $x_0$. Consequently $-\sqrt{2}=v(x_0)\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $y\in O$ be an element with the property $v(y)>\sqrt{2}$. Then for every $x\in J$
$
v(yx)=v(y)+v(x)>0,
$
hence $yJ\subseteq O$.
